# Property 'id' does not exist on type 'never'. on map function

Tags: reactjs, typescript

So i have started learning Typescript and im a little stuck when it comes to typing the map function below. When i do nothing i get an error: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'never'. But if i add 'item:any' to the params of the function it fixes it.

But everywhere i read they mention that any should be the last resort. Can someone explain to me how to type this correctly?

Bonus: There is also an error with the section 'error.message' which has the same error which i cant seem to resolve either without adding any.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);


 useEffect(() => {
 fetch("https://api.publicapis.org/entries")
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(
    (result) => {
      setIsLoaded(true);
      setItems(result);
    },
   
    (error) => {
      setIsLoaded(true);
      setError(error);
    }
  )
}, [])

if (error) {
  return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
} else if (!isLoaded) {
  return <div>Loading...</div>;
} else {
return (
  <ul>
    {items.map((item) => (
      <li key={item.id}>
        {item.name} {item.price}
      </li>
    ))}
  </ul>
);
 }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can "easily" fix this by giving TypeScript an hint on what is the **type of array of objects** you are iterating with `map`.

This can be done by using the generic parameter that `useState` receives, here is a sample:

```
interface Item {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  price: number;
}

// Then you need to pass in the type of what you will have in the useState
const [items, setItems] = useState<Array<Item>>([]);
```

The problem you are facing is due to TypeScript having no clue on what is the `type` of the objects that `items` may or may not contain. Which will make `items` fallback to the type of `never[]`, which is just a way of TypeScript warning you that you made something wrong and that you can't use it that way.